# Cassandra batch if not exists duplicate behaviour

Tags: cassandra

I am batch inserting multiple rows for the same partition using if not exists. From my testing it looks like if any of the rows is a duplicate all inserts fail and no rows are inserted. I want to to keep the if not exists behavior but not fail the batch if there are duplicates and still insert the non-duplicate rows. Is there any way to tell Cassandra not to fail the batch if there are duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

Note the following documentation which most likely applies to your version of Cassandra.

> In Cassandra 2.0.6 and later, you can batch conditional updates introduced as lightweight transactions in Cassandra 2.0. Only updates made to the same partition can be included in the batch because the underlying Paxos implementation works at the granularity of the partition. You can group updates that have conditions with those that do not, but when a single statement in a batch uses a condition, the entire batch is committed using a single Paxos proposal, as if all of the conditions contained in the batch apply.

This confirms what you're experiencing is intended behaviour. Given the underlying batch mechanism, it is not easy to do what you want through CQL.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html#reference_ds_djf_xdd_xj__batch-conditional

Without knowing the details of your use case, my initial thoughts would be to question if you really need to use a BATCH statement like this. If you need to update multiple tables based on one event in your application, you can still batch together statements based on the same IF NOT EXISTS condition.

Comment: My use case is straight forward. I have two separate processes inserting data into the same table. Data from the first process A, takes precedence over data from the other process B. Process B first reads from the table and makes sure data that it is about to inserts does not already exist. The issue is that between the read and write data could of been inserted by process A. This is why I have process B do the inserts with the IF NOT EXISTS, to avoid data from process B overwriting data from process A.

Comment: That makes sense to use lightweight transactions (IF NOT EXISTS), but why do you need to use the batch statement.

Comment: I am actually doing this through the Spark Cassandra connector which by default groups all inserts for the same partition keys in a single batch statement.

Comment: You should update your question with this info. There are configuration options for the batching, available at: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md

Comment: Thanks, I did look at those. I was hoping there was something on the Cassandra side to get around the issue.